# Updating table with SqliteDataAdapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, datagridview

I have a bit of an issue when it comes to updating view in datagridview. My function successfully deletes selected row from database but DataAdapter does not fill datatable dt. Function with the same structure works perfectly when adding rows.

```
    private string ConString;

    private SQLiteCommand cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    SQLiteDataAdapter DB;


    // Function to delete rows
    public void DeleteRow(string value)
    {
        string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Trades WHERE ID = " + value;
        try
        {
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(ConString);

            sql_con.Open();
            cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sqlStatement;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            dt.Clear();
            DB.Fill(dt);
        }
        finally
        {
            sql_con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because your `DB` does not have _any_ data within. It does not have any `SELECT` statement or whatever.. What data do you expect to fill your datatable exactly? And 
learn [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: Why you recreate DataAdapter every time? Meaning of dataadapter -it is always the same. You just specify Update, Insert and Delete command for  adapter. Update method of the adapter will call these command for each row having appropriate status in dt. Exactly in this order: event in GUI changes  DataTable or DataSet and DataAdapter transfers changes to database.